# DatePicker control

Tags: jquery

I would like to know if there are any relative Calendar Controls avaiable.
I want the calendar to show the normal calendar and also allow the user to pick some relative options such as Yesterday, Today, Previous month, year like that..the options are limited though.

But when they select those relative options, it should not render the date, because I want to store the Yesterday as Yesterday in the DB, so that when ever then run the query, it should be able to pick yesterday's results..not a static date.

So, is there any control avaiable which satisifies the above requirements, please do let me know.

Thanks and appreciate your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Look at jQuery UI's [DatePicker](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/).

Comment: This just is a calendar control. This doesn't satisfy my requirements.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you're trying to accomplish, a calendar control isn't really the issue. You just want shortcuts for using relative date values in your queries.

I can't imagine a full integration with a date picker that would work well for that. If for some reason you wanted to add those links into a datepicker popup element (say at the top, bottom, or sides), you could extend the control to provide them. However, it seems like more trouble than it's worth to me - I would just wrap them all up in a div and toggle its visibility.